# How do I get a value from a JSON 2 dimensional structure (nested dictionaries)?

Tags: json, xcode, swift, tableview, afnetworking

I'm having difficulty getting a value from a 2 dimensional JSON structure and putting it in a TableView.
I used AFNetworking to get the JSON data. This code builds in Xcode 6 beta 7:

```
func apiConnetion() {
        var result: NSArray = []
        manager.GET("https://example.com/",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                result = responseObject as NSArray
                println(result)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.commentData = result
                    self.commentTableView!.reloadData()
                })

            },

            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("error")
                println(" \(error.localizedDescription ) ")

        })

    }
```

`println(result)` prints the structure like this:

```
{
"id" = 1;
"name" = "Test1";
"category" =
           "id" = 1;
           "name" = "justtest";
}
{
"id" = 2;
"name" = "Test2";
"category" =
         "id" = 2;
         "name" = "justtest1";
}
```

How do I get the category name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `NSArray` with two entries. Use `indexPath.row` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to select the right entry. This returns a dictionary. Select the value corresponding to "category" which returns an `NSDictionary?` because dictionary accesses always return optional values in case the key doesn't exist. Use a `?` to unwrap that. A `?` is safer than a `!` here which would crash trying to unwrap nil if "category" was not a key. Now lookup the "name" which returns a `NSString?`. Finally use the *nil coalescing operator* to get the string or an empty string if "category" or "name" weren't valid keys.

```
let name = result[indexPath.row]["category"]?["name"] ?? ""
```